# How to divide a 3d model to get different colors on Unity?

Tags: modeling, unity

[image: The 3d model]

I have a scanned 3d model and i need to divide it in several sections in order to put different  colors on those section and afterwards import in to unity. I read on internet that i can do this by generating submeshes in my piece but i don't understand how, could you explain me how to do that? (i'm using blender 2.75a)

As you can see, the model is made by a single mesh (the model is called "terminado"). First, someone made a 3d scan of this piece and afterwards he built the 3d model and made some corrections on Rhinoceros (as a stl file). After that, i just imported that file on blender and that's all. I would be very thankful if you could help me realize how to do it.

Comment: Please show your 3D model or reasonable facsimile as a Blender 3D view screen capture image. It helps readers to understand the question.  This site has tutorial resources as well. In general any mesh can be broken up into different meshes.  Any face of a mesh can have a different material/color.

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/GeMYO.jpg

Here is the picture. As you can see, the model is made by a single mesh (the model is called "terminado"). First, someone made a 3d scan of this piece and afterwards he built the 3d model and made some corrections on Rhinoceros (as a stl file). After that, i just imported that file on blender and that's all. I would be very thankful if you could help me realize how to do it.

Comment: Any reason you have to divide it? Why can't you just use a Texture with the colors you want?  Your asking for a basic tutorial on how to use Blender... You would have a greater chance of getting an answer if you show errors in your process so people knew what part your having trouble with.